# How to get product amount

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

I'm creating an e-commerce on React Native. I'm using Accept payment from [oficial documentation, on Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet#react-native-collect-payment-details).

The backend code is the following:

```js
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: 1099, // how to get my amount???
    currency: 'eur',
    customer: customer.id,
    // In the latest version of the API, specifying the `automatic_payment_methods` parameter is optional because Stripe enables its functionality by default.
    automatic_payment_methods: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  });
```

Currently, everything is returning `10,99`. How to get real price on product from backend?

I'm trying to use `amount: req.body.totalPrice`, but nothing changed.

Comment: have you already solved this problem?